# What would one call a lunar "mansion"?

Tags: single-word-requests

In multiple cultures' historical astronomical traditions, a lunar "mansion" referred to a star of a constellation, which the moon passed over in its orbit. In the cultures it occurred in, domestic or architectural metaphor is often used: mansion in English, *xiù* or lodge in Chinese, *burj* or tower for the constellations, and *manzil* or dwelling for the stars in Arabic, etc.

I haven't encountered any Esperanto translation of the term. Should it be calqued as *(luna) loĝejo/domo*, or translated some other way? Is there any extant Esperanto writing on this that has referred to lunar mansions? What is the best way to refer to them?

Answer (score 1):

For this astrological associative term "house" is also used. So *domo* (or *loĝejo*) should do. It is neither too western specific as you noted, nor would a systematic term (?) or neologism (too small field) be better.

I am not familiar with astrology, so the last check: whether the term conflicts with similar ones. Is there an other notion *house/home*? Then *loĝejo* would be better.

There is a difference with mansion/dwelling, though for instance in Italian "casa lunare" is the translation, hence "house" (*domo*) would fit. *hejmo* probably is too literally though: *home of the stars*. *vilao* or other specialisations of *domo* might be too misleading.